# One to many relation with Factory Boy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I have a many-to-one relationship in my SQLAlchemy models. One report has many samples (simplified for brevity):

```py
class Sample(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    sample_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    report_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('report.report_id', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True, nullable=False)
    report = relationship('Report', back_populates='samples')

class Report(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    report_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    samples = relationship('Sample', back_populates='report')
```

Now in my tests, I want to be able to generate a `Sample` instance, or a `Report` instance, and fill in the missing relationships.

```py
class ReportFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Report
    report_id = Faker('pyint')
    samples = RelatedFactoryList('tests.factories.SampleFactory', size=3)

class SampleFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sample
    sample_id = Faker('pyint')
    report = SubFactory(ReportFactory)
```

When I go to create an instance of these, the factories get stuck in an infinite loop:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

However, if I try to use `SelfAttribute`s to stop the infinite loop, I end up with a report without any samples:

```py
class ReportFactory(BaseFactory):
    samples = RelatedFactoryList('tests.factories.SampleFactory', size=3, report_id=SelfAttribute('..report_id'))

class SampleFactory(BaseFactory):
    report = SubFactory(ReportFactory, samples=[])
```

```
report = factories.ReportFactory()
l = len(report.samples) # 0
```

However, if I generate a `Sample` with `SampleFactory()`, it correctly has a `Report` object.

How should I correctly design my factories such that `SampleFactory()` will generate a `Sample` with associated `Report`, and `ReportFactory()` will generate a `Report` with 2 associated `Samples`, without infinite loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My final solution was actually a lot simpler than I thought:

```
class ReportFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Report

    samples = RelatedFactoryList('tests.factories.SampleFactory', 'report', size=3)


class SampleFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sample

    report = SubFactory(ReportFactory, samples=[])
```

**The key thing was using the second argument to `RelatedFactoryList`, which has to correspond to the parent link on the child**, in this case `'report'`. In addition, I used `SubFactory(ReportFactory, samples=[])`, which ensures that no extra samples are created on the parent if I construct a single sample.

With this setup, I can construct a sample that will have a `Report` associated with it, and that report only has 1 child `Sample`. Conversely, I can construct a `Report` that will automatically be populated with 3 child Samples.

I don't think there's any need to generate the actual model IDs, because SQLAlchemy will do that automatically once the models are actually inserted into the database. However, if you want to do that without using the database, I think @Xelnor's solution of `report_id = factory.SelfAttribute('report.id')` will work.

The only outstanding issue I have is with overriding the list of samples on the Report (e.g. `ReportFactory(samples = [SampleFactory()])`), but I've opened an issue documenting this bug: https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/636

Comment: This works too, but only due to the underlying features of your ORM: when you read `report.samples`, SQLAlchemy will dynamically fetch a list of `Sample` objects in the DB (or session) pointing to that specific `Report`.  If you're not working with an ORM, you have to link them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did mention SQLAlchemy in the question, though.

Answer (score 3):

The `RelatedFactory` declaration is evaluated once the instance has been created:

1. The `Report` is instantiated
2. 3 calls to `SampleFactory` are performed
3. The `Report` instantiated in step 1 is returned

In order to populate the field on the `Report` instances, you have to *link* the `Sample` instances to the `Report` at step 2.

A possible implementation would be:

```
class SampleFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample

    @classmethod
    def _after_postgeneration(cls, instance, create, results=None):
        if instance.report is not None and instance not in instance.report.samples:
            instance.report.samples.append(instance)

    id = factory.Faker('pyint')
    # Enfore `post_samples = None` to prevent creating additional samples
    report = factory.SubFactory('example.ReportFactory', samples=[], post_samples=None)
    report_id = factory.SelfAttribute('report.id')

class ReportFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Report

    id = factory.Faker('pyint')
    # Set samples = [] if needed by `Report.__init__`
    samples = []
    # Named `post_samples` to mark that they are instantiated
    # *after* the `Report` is ready (and never passed to the `samples` kwarg)
    post_samples = factory.RelatedFactoryList(SampleFactory, 'report', size=3)
```

With that code, when you call `ReportFactory`, you:

1. Generate a `Report` without any samples
2. Generate 3 samples, passing them a reference to the just-generated report
3. Upon creation, those `Sample` instances attach themselves to `Report.samples`

Comment: But since you named the `RelatedFactoryList` `post_samples`, won't the the generated `Report` have no `Sample`s in it?

Comment: No, because we're attaching each `Sample` to its `Report` manually when it is created, in the `_after_postgeneration` hook.